# Can't integrate $ \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \left( k\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{x}} \right) + e_{gen} = \rho c\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{t}} $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**First off, I apologize for the lack of information in the title, I had to shorten it due to the 150 character limit.**

The question I am attempting can be seen here:

$ e_{gen}$ , $k$, $\rho$ (density)  , and $ c $ (specific heat capacity) are constant with respect to distance, $x$, and time, $t$

$ \frac{ \partial}{\partial{x}} \left( k \frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{x}} \right) + e_{gen} = \rho c \frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{t}} $

Show how under steady state conditions, this equation reduces to $$ \frac{d^2T}{dx^2} + \frac{e_{gen}}{k} = 0 $$

Honestly I'm at a loss as to how to tackle this question. I have searched for examples to base it off and I can't fully grasp what to do.

Also, I am unsure if I integrated the other questions on the question sheet correctly. I  **did** do the other questions, and the answers match up with the solutions, but I don't know if my method was correct or if I kinda brute forced it to look right, without actually using the correct method.

My solution to the third question can be seen in the image below, with a separate image containing the questions.

[Solution to Question 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWM7v.jpg)

[Question Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMWqv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Under steady state conditions, $T$ is constant with respect to time. So $\partial_t T = 0$, and your equation becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dx}( \kappa \frac{d}{dx} T) + e_{gen} = 0
$$
Since $\kappa$ is constant (and non-zero), then pull $\kappa$ out of the differentiation, divide through by $\kappa$ to get
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} T + \frac{e_{gen}}{\kappa}=0.
$$